# Select Datagrid row using Spacebar in Silverlight application

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, datagrid

I have a Datagrid in Silverlight application. The user is able to get the focus on Datagrid using Tab key and move between various rows using Up and Down arrow Key.

Please advice, how to fire row select event when the user hits the Spacebar Key for an selected row.

Below is the code snippet:

```
<Custom:ClientControl  
x:Class="TestNamespace.Modules.Views.SampleView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
mc:Ignorable="d"  
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" 
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dg" ...>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoSomething}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
<sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apprently the solution turned out to be very smiple.

Step 1: Add KeyDown to the Datagrid.

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dg" KeyDown="dg_KeyDown">
```

Step 2: In .XAML.CS file inside Datagrid KeyDown event invoke the method which handles MouseLeftButtonUp event.

```
private void dg_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Space)
    {
        this.viewModel.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding Key="Space" Command="{Binding DoSomething}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

You can bind the selected value to a property in your View model.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your help.
However, I see an error after adding above line in XAML file "The member "InputBindings" is not recognised or is not accessible". I have added the code snippet for reference.

Comment: Is it 100% necessary to use <sdk:DataGrid> over <DataGrid>?